# Is there a CSS method to style only the first row of wrapping elements?

Tags: html, css

Say you have a responsive-width container full of inline-block elements. Some of these elements hit the edge of the container and drop to new lines. This is great! ...Unless for some reason you want to apply style rules to only the FIRST line of the elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/nshdnazw/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="thinger"></div>
  <div class="thinger"></div>
  <div class="thinger"></div>
  <div class="thinger"></div>
  <div class="thinger"></div> 
  <div class="thinger"></div>
  <div class="thinger"></div>
  <div class="thinger"></div>
  <div class="thinger"></div>
  <div class="thinger"></div>
  <div class="thinger"></div>
  <div class="thinger"></div>
  <div class="thinger"></div>
  <div class="thinger"></div>
  <div class="thinger"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #ababab;
}

.thinger {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #666666;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

In the fiddle above, say for instance I want the top line of items to be slightly darker, or I wanted to remove the top margin. I could apply a negative margin to the container, but then the container moves. It's a hack instead of a fix. I can't think of a CSS solution for changing the color, though.

Text has a solution, using the ::first-line pseudoselector. Is there a similar method for inline blocks?

Comment: No. You'd need scripting.

Comment: ... unless you overlayed a transparent slightly darker shade of color to manipulate whatever's underneath it

Comment: That would effectively disable any links and other functionality in the blocks.

Comment: @isherwood: not necessarily, `pointer-events` could prevent that (if supported in the browser, but it adds more complexity than just using scripting).

Comment: You can z-index content from inside above the top without changing what's underneath, but it's a good point you make.

Comment: That's true. Might be worth posting as an answer.

Comment: Though technically that's not CSS-only. It requires more markup.

Comment: Hah! It's hacky, but that would totally work for the color issue. It's really a pity if there's no css solution for just blindly applying rules to first/specific lines though, it'd be shockingly useful.

Comment: for the overlay, it can be a pseudo with a repeating gradient, or maybe a background gradient to the container  with a mix-blend mode  for the boxes ...  http://jsfiddle.net/nshdnazw/2/ not an answer to my point of view :(

Comment: If you know the max and min amount of elements for row 1 and the elements is fixed width, you could use media query to target only the first row.

Comment: @GCyrillus I was actually thinking the same, beside media query, but instead of gradient, one could use a svg as background image, which gives more overlay options.

Comment: @LGSon i believe the SVG would be much better, cross browsers, olders won't mind it !

Comment: @GCyrillus After some more testing I agree fully with that ... using media query gets really messy :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using your existing HTML.

It moves the default background color to a `::before` pseudo element, and the background for the first row to an `::after` pseudo element.

See code comments for explanation.

```
.container {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #ababab;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;        /* behind pseudo elements */
}

.thinger {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.thinger::before, .thinger::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;  /* positioned relative to .container */
  z-index: -1;         /* to prevent covering any text */
  width: 100px;        /* same width as .thinger */
  height: 100px;       /* same height as .thinger */
}

.thinger::before {
  background: #666;    /* default background */
}

.thinger::after {
  top: 10px;           /* top row only  (.thinger's margin-top is 10px.)  */
  background: brown;   /* background of top row only */
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/a1nk8vrq/1)

Comment: Clever, but probably it's worth mentioning about limitations of the method, for example semitransparent background colors will not work as expected: `.thinger::after { background: rgba(255,0,0,0.25); }`. And yet variable dimensions of thingers, etc.

Comment: Good points.  My method obviously requires `.thinger`s to be the same size, but I hadn't considered the semitransparency issue.

Answer (score 2):

Even CSS has `::first-line` pseudo-element you cannot style elements contained in  first line. That's because contained elements are children of the container but not that first-line pseudo-element.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there isn't any way CSS could check for elements wich have a specific position, so my best CSS solution, that could fit for your problem, is to just change the background color in the section of the first line. For example take an empty div-element, scale it up so it covers the whole first row/line (width is responsive too of course) and fix its position above the first row.
Now you can simply work with the z-index and background color to make a fixed or absolute, colored underlayer for the first line.

Something like this (z-index sadly don't seem to work):

```css
.container {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #ababab;
}

.thinger {
  background-color: #666666;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 2;
}

div.background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 8px;
  width: 48%;
  height: 105px;
  background-color: #98bf21;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
 <div class="background"></div>

<div class="container">
  <span class="thinger">
  </span>
  <span class="thinger">
  </span>
  <span class="thinger">
  </span>
  <span class="thinger">
  </span>
  <span class="thinger">
  </span>
  <span class="thinger">
  </span>
  <span class="thinger">
  </span>
  <span class="thinger">
  </span>
  <span class="thinger">
  </span>
  <span class="thinger">
  </span>
  <span class="thinger">
  </span>
  <span class="thinger">
  </span>
  <span class="thinger">
  </span>
  <span class="thinger">
  </span>
  <span class="thinger">
  </span>
</div>
```

PS:
You know that if you put text in the boxes they move around?

Comment: an extra div or a pseudo would be an idea indeed, but not reliable in my opinion: example with the pseudo (instead your extra div) and a mix-blend-mode ..http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLYWrz